# Add line numbers to a textarea/other multiline text input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How could I add line numbers to a textarea/input box?

Like VS Code's line numbering where it's aligned to the right, in the same font, and everything?

[what I'm looking for]

```
   1 Line 1 text
   2 Line 2, etc.
```

...

```
  99 Line text
 100 Line 100
```

...

```
 999 Line 999
1000 Line 1000
```

Comment: You would use something like codemirror for something like this. Especially if you want it to look like VS Code.

Comment: In case you need a code editor you can just use [Monaco editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) which is the editor used in VS code.

Comment: You should have just googled it first. Check this [link](https://www.webtips.dev/add-line-numbers-to-html-textarea#:~:text=Style%20the%20Textarea,-Now%20let%27s%20have&text=We%20can%20use%20the%20built,a%20%3A%3Abefore%20pseudo-element)

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/bq3wogxs/

Comment: @ChrisG Could you put it in an answer so I can mark my question as answered?

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi I googled it and couldn't find anything helpful. That's literally the reason why I came here, and also the reason this website exists.

Comment: I have created a line numbering project that works very well with line wrap: https://codepen.io/CodemasterUnited/pen/oNQexQp